# Nested XML file parsing in Databricks using spark-scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to parse a nested xml file with multiple row tags using spark/scala. After parsing I have to load the data into a table. However, I am not able to convert multiple row tags into a proper tabular format. I am using spark-xml library in azure databricks cluster. Could someone kindly help.

Below is the sample source and schema of the file. The original file is around 20MB in size

```
</images>
```

---

```
    SCHEMA:

schv    
cnt          
ctd          
cgr        
st            
pd           
sid         
pid         
nm             
ct             
state            
pcd       
cty          
pty      
rshp     
rshp_type
attrb           
tmzn         
clsgn         
edlag           
bcaslag        
num              
mjrnum         
mirnum         
affil            
afffil_pid  
url              
mktid         
mktid_type    
imgtyp       
wdt            
hgt           
prmy          
ctrgy         
uri              
ctdtline
```

Comment: How you are exploding your XML data? Can you please share how you are trying to use XML library..

Comment: How do you read the data, can you share the code you tried, what did not work for you? and what is your expected output?

Comment: @koiralo I have tried the below.

Comment: @koiralo I have tried the below.
val df = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","on").option("inferschema","true").load("filepath")

Comment: Expected output :

Comment: I am not able to paste the output here. But the output should be in a format as below. I a m pasting few sample columns and values.

Comment: schv     cnt           ctd           cgr         st             pd           
2 On(r) TV: Sources 2021-04-11 cgr 2021 Gracenote. All rights reserved 2021-04-11T00:00:00 xx

Comment: Each column from schema should be assigned with a value from source xml